# Remove points with less than two lines connected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I want to delete points created with Network Analyst with less than two lines connected. Is there any smart way to do that? Is it possible to count the number of lines the point is connected to?

[image: The points marked with yellow must be deleted]

Comment: Do you understand that if your delete the points in yellow the lines they are located on will be collapsed into a two vertex straight segments?

Comment: What you are describing Jonas is the Valency, there are many questions with answers on GIS SE that already cover this topic.

Comment: @Alex It's two different shape-files. The points are generated based on the lines where all junctions are found.